# How to track digital product sales from third-party vendors

Tags: tracking, download, woocommerce

Hopefully this question is in the right place. We are using WordPress with WooCommerce. We sell homeschool curriculum in print and digital versions. Our distributors currently sell  our print curriculum by purchasing bulk at wholesale prices and we ship it to them. However, some of our distributors want to sell our digital curriculum too.

I am having some trouble figuring out how to do this and keep the distributors accountable. For instance, if we give them the digital content to sell on their website, how do we verify that they are reporting true numbers to us and not skewing the numbers in their favor?

I guess what I am looking for is recommendations or advice on the best way to keep track of sales of our digital products from our distributors to maintain a degree of accountability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow a distributor to sell your digital products on their website while trusting their sales reports, you're going to have to log the sales or usage in one way or another.

If your content is going to be available on their website without their customers going to your website to pay for or view the products, you will have to monitor this usage.

If you hand over your digital products to them where they can host them on their servers there's very little way to monitor this if they are being dishonest. But one thing you can do is on their checkout pages, track when sales were made through a PHP analytics send. If they start serving up checkout pages without this code then you know they are gaming you. You can also add tracking code to the digital content on their servers to monitor usage rate, and if the tracking code isn't served then you know there's a problem.

A potentially better way to allow others to sell your content without leaving their site is to serve up the content through your own servers. This way you can monitor how many users there are which will tell you if their sales reports are accurate. You can load your digital files onto their website through AJAX, PHP or JS.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I like your last suggestion. I was just looking at affiliate program API's that seem to do what you suggested and it seems like it may be a viable option for our situation. Any input on that?

Comment: Here are some AJAX load examples if they are helpful to you: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp